# Biblatex, number followed by dot in bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I'm using BibTeX and `biblatex` for my documents. I'm now writing an article and am required to write the bibliography with the following style:

> 1. C. Tsallis et al., Phys. Rev. A 63 (2001) 042104.

While rest of the style can be achieved using the `biblatex-phys` package, I don't know how to set the style for the reference number, i.e. how to change `[1]` to `1.`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add the following to your preamble:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1\adddot}
\setlength{\biblabelsep}{5pt}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=phys,biblabel=brackets]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1\adddot}
\setlength{\biblabelsep}{5pt}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]